# How to track rankings with google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, ranking

I wondered if it is possible to track the rankings with the google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on?

Because in Analytics > acquisition > search console > landingpages   you can see the rankings of the period which is setted ("Last N Days" in Report Configurations of Spreadsheet).

At the moment we are tracking the pageviews of last 90 days. We would like to track also the average ranking position of last 14 days. Do you know what I would have to set in the report configurations (propably metrics and dimensions)? Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution in the internet.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Found a free addon, that solves this https://searchanalyticsforsheets.com/
Unfortunately (but logically) it only tracks clicked landingpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is doing perfectly but only for 100 sites. 
https://www.ranktank.org/